# JOLT shift transformation: filter by the value of the property (not the name)

Tags: java, json, tree, jolt

I am trying to transform a JSON using Jolt transformation looking for some input here.
I am trying to filter by the value of the attribute.

**My goal is to get an array that contains only the items with the action 'remove'.**

Here is my input and expected output:

*Input*:

```json
{
  "id": 11,
  "item": [
    {
      "id": "11_1",
      "action": "add",
      "item": [
        {
          "id": "11_1_1",
          "action": "add",
          "item": [
            {
              "id": "11_1_1_1",
              "action": "remove"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "11_1_2",
          "action": "remove",
          "item": [
            {
              "id": "11_1_2_1",
              "action": "remove"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Expected output*:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "11_1_1_1",
    "action": "remove"
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_2",
    "action": "remove"
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_2_1",
    "action": "remove"
  }
]
```

Can you please help me to write a simple spec that will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let's flatten the JSON by determining the cases to be `"item"` vs.
  `else case("*")` while walking the tree within the first spec
- and label the individual arrays by their `action` names
- and then pick objects of the `remove` array the last spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {
        "*": {
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "item": {
                "*": {
                  "*": "@(1,id)[&1].&"
                }
              },
              "*": "j[&1].&"
            }
          },
          "*": "i[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@(0,action)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "remove": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the playground site for jolt(http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
More little Q plz:
If I want to filter by inner value:
```json
"item": [
  {
    "id": "11_1_2_1",
    "type": {
      "id": "1_zz",
      "typeName": "zz"
    }
  }
],
```
By the typeName of the type
My goal is to get an array that contains only the items with the typeName 'zz'.
Do u know how to do it?

Comment: Hi @Michal , it's already a completed question, can you ask a new one, I'll be trying to answer when I'm available. Have a nice day!

Comment: ok, thanks ahead!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73598200/jolt-shift-transformation-filter-by-inner-value-of-a-property-not-the-name

Answer (score 0):

You may consider another library *Josson* that a simple statement can do the job. And the function even supports unknown and unlimited number of path levels.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"id\": 11," +
    "  \"item\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"id\": \"11_1\"," +
    "      \"action\": \"add\"," +
    "      \"item\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "          \"id\": \"11_1_1\"," +
    "          \"action\": \"add\"," +
    "          \"item\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "              \"id\": \"11_1_1_1\"," +
    "              \"action\": \"remove\"" +
    "            }" +
    "          ]" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "          \"id\": \"11_1_2\"," +
    "          \"action\": \"remove\"," +
    "          \"item\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "              \"id\": \"11_1_2_1\"," +
    "              \"action\": \"remove\"" +
    "            }" +
    "          ]" +
    "        }" +
    "      ]" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}");
```

Transformation

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "cumulateCollect(item[action='remove']*.field(item:), item).flatten(1)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
[ {
  "id" : "11_1_2",
  "action" : "remove"
}, {
  "id" : "11_1_1_1",
  "action" : "remove"
}, {
  "id" : "11_1_2_1",
  "action" : "remove"
} ]
```