# JOLT shift transformation: filter by inner value of a property (not the name)

Tags: java, json, tree, jolt

I am trying to transform a JSON using Jolt transformation looking for some input here.
I am trying to filter by the inner value of the attribute.

**My goal is to get an array that contains only the items with the typeName 'xx'.**

Here is my input and expected output:

*Input*:

```json
{
  "id": 11,
  "item": [
    {
      "id": "11_1",
      "action": "add",
      "type": {
        "id": "11_1_xx",
        "typeName": "xx"
      },
      "item": [
        {
          "id": "11_1_1",
          "action": "add",
          "type": {
            "id": "11_1_1_zz",
            "typeName": "zz"
          },
          "item": [
            {
              "id": "11_1_1_1",
              "action": "add",
              "type": {
                "id": "11_1_1_1_xx",
                "typeName": "xx"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "11_1_2",
          "action": "add",
          "type": {
            "id": "11_1_2_xx",
            "typeName": "xx"
          },
          "item": [
            {
              "id": "11_1_2_1",
              "action": "add",
              "type": {
                "id": "11_1_2_1_zz",
                "typeName": "zz"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Expected output*:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "11_1",
    "action": "add",
    "type": {
      "id": "11_1_xx",
      "typeName": "xx"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_1_1",
    "action": "add",
    "type": {
      "id": "11_1_1_1_xx",
      "typeName": "xx"
    }
}, {
    "id": "11_1_2",
    "action": "add",
    "type": {
      "id": "11_1_2_xx",
      "typeName": "xx"
    }
  }
]
```

Can you please help me to write a simple spec that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to separate the objects by both the `id` and `type.typeName` values in the first transformation spec, in order to filter out by `type.typeName=xx` within the next spec long with distinctly picked `id` values through use of **`@(1,id).@(1,typeName)`** identifiers on the Right Hand Side for the leaf elements such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {
        "*": {
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "item": {
                "*": {
                  "type": {
                    "@(1,id)": "@(1,id).@(1,typeName).id",
                    "@(1,action)": "@(1,id).@(1,typeName).action",
                    "*": "@(1,id).@(1,typeName).&1.&" // &1 replicates key name "type"
                  }
                }
              },
              "type": {
                "@(1,id)": "@(1,id).@(1,typeName).id",
                "@(1,action)": "@(1,id).@(1,typeName).action",
                "*": "@(1,id).@(1,typeName).&1.&" // & replicates the values of the elements nested within the "type" object
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "@(1,id)": "@(1,id).@(1,typeName).id",
            "@(1,action)": "@(1,id).@(1,typeName).action",
            "*": "@(1,id).@(1,typeName).&1.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "xx": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may consider another library *Josson* that a simple statement can do the job. And the function even supports unknown and unlimited number of path levels.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"id\": 11," +
    "  \"item\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"id\": \"11_1\"," +
    "      \"action\": \"add\"," +
    "      \"type\": {" +
    "        \"id\": \"11_1_xx\"," +
    "        \"typeName\": \"xx\"" +
    "      }," +
    "      \"item\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "          \"id\": \"11_1_1\"," +
    "          \"action\": \"add\"," +
    "          \"type\": {" +
    "            \"id\": \"11_1_1_zz\"," +
    "            \"typeName\": \"zz\"" +
    "          }," +
    "          \"item\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "              \"id\": \"11_1_1_1\"," +
    "              \"action\": \"add\"," +
    "              \"type\": {" +
    "                \"id\": \"11_1_1_1_xx\"," +
    "                \"typeName\": \"xx\"" +
    "              }" +
    "            }" +
    "          ]" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "          \"id\": \"11_1_2\"," +
    "          \"action\": \"add\"," +
    "          \"type\": {" +
    "            \"id\": \"11_1_2_xx\"," +
    "            \"typeName\": \"xx\"" +
    "          }," +
    "          \"item\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "              \"id\": \"11_1_2_1\"," +
    "              \"action\": \"add\"," +
    "              \"type\": {" +
    "                \"id\": \"11_1_2_1_zz\"," +
    "                \"typeName\": \"zz\"" +
    "              }" +
    "            }" +
    "          ]" +
    "        }" +
    "      ]" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}");
```

Transformation

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "cumulateCollect(item[type.typeName='xx']*.field(item:), item).flatten(1)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
[ {
  "id" : "11_1",
  "action" : "add",
  "type" : {
    "id" : "11_1_xx",
    "typeName" : "xx"
  }
}, {
  "id" : "11_1_2",
  "action" : "add",
  "type" : {
    "id" : "11_1_2_xx",
    "typeName" : "xx"
  }
}, {
  "id" : "11_1_1_1",
  "action" : "add",
  "type" : {
    "id" : "11_1_1_1_xx",
    "typeName" : "xx"
  }
} ]
```